# Can I fake a CE-HTML key constant from javascript?

Tags: javascript, keycode

I would like to fake i.e trigger a keycode event which matches a custom keycode defined in the CE-HTML standard for NetTV. Is this possible **from the javascript console** in chrome / firefox? I tried:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 406; // this is the custom keycode value for constant VK_BLUE (blue button on remote control)
$("input").trigger(e);
```

But it has no effect. I have a feeling this might be restricted.

If its not possible, can I send a code like that from my operating system (OSX) by triggering that keycode event somehow? Or is 406 completely meaningless outside of the NetTV environment?

Comment: have you tried this instead? `var e = jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 64 });` http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: I realised this DOES work. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: done, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to fake an event object like so:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 64 });
$("input").trigger(e);
```

[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Applescript to send you keycode:

```
tell application "yourApplication"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to key code 406
end tell
```

Comment: This works to send a keycode but only if it is a recognised keycode. I dont think 406 is one of those.